# Showing the contents of a SPAN using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, html

I have this code. I've done this for years now but I'm stumped with the result of this example. The purpose is to make the text box visible and put the contents of the clicked SPAN tag in it.

```
document.onclick = CaptureClickedElement;

function CaptureClickedElement(e)
{
var EventElement;
if(e==null)
    EventElement = event.srcElement;// IE
else
    EventElement = e.target;// Firefox

if( EventElement.tagName == "SPAN")
    {
    document.getElementById("divTXT").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("Span1").innerHTML;
    alert(document.getElementById("Span1").innerHTML)
    }
}
```

Strangely though, it DOES show the contents but also shows open/close SPAN tags at the end of it. If I alert ther results, the same thing is shown.

Please find the attached screen shot of it here.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Thanks!

Here is the HTML (copied from comments by mplungjan)

```
<style type="text/css"> 
 #divOuter { 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 70px; 
   border: 1px solid blue; 
   float: left; 
 } 
 </style>

<body> 
  <div> 
    <form name="frm" method="post" action=""> 
      <div id="divTXT" style="display:none"> 
        <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" value="" size="30" /> 
      </div> 
    </form> 
  </div> 
  <div id="divOuter"> 
    <span id="Span1">hi, this is a test.<span> 
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">

#divOuter {
 width: 100px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 float: left;
}


</style>

Comment: <body>
<div>
 <form name="frm" method="post" action="">
  <div id="divTXT" style="display:none">
   <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" value="" size="30" />
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="divOuter">
<span id="Span1">hi, this is a test.<span>
</div>

</body>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure problem:

```
<span id="Span1">hi, this is a test.<span>
```

Note the absence of a proper close to the span.

Comment: Well spotted. I did not even get to spot that while I pasted the html in :O

Comment: @itsols not stupid - I've seen such weirdness many times.  When you get the innerHTML of an element and it returns to you a tag fragment, you should automatically suspect a structure issue.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use .innerText (for IE) and .text for others.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but neither innerText nor text work. They give the 'undefined' alert.

Comment: No need for innerText/textContent